# Golang main difference from CSP-Language by Hoare

Tags: go, concurrency

Look at this statement taken from [The examples from Tony Hoare's seminal 1978 paper](https://godoc.org/github.com/thomas11/csp):

> Go's design was strongly influenced by Hoare's paper. Although Go differs significantly from the example language used in the paper, the examples still translate rather easily. The biggest difference apart from syntax is that Go models the conduits of concurrent communication explicitly as channels, while the processes of Hoare's language send messages directly to each other, similar to Erlang. Hoare hints at this possibility in section 7.3, but with the limitation that "each port is connected to exactly one other port in another process", in which case it would be a mostly syntactic difference.

I'm confused.

Processes in Hoare's language communicate directly to each other. Go routines communicate also directly to each other but using channels.

So what impact has the limitation in golang. What is the real difference?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer requires a fuller understanding of Hoare's work on CSP. The progression of his work can be summarised in three stages:

- based on Dijkstra's semaphore's, Hoare developed *monitors*. These are as used in Java, except Java's implementation contains a mistake (see Welch's article [Wot No Chickens](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/java-threads/0.html)). It's unfortunate that Java ignored Hoare's later work.
- CSP grew out of this. Initially, CSP required direct exchange from process A to process B. This rendezvous approach is used by Ada and Erlang.
- CSP was completed by 1985, when [his Book](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf) was first published. This final version of CSP includes channels as used in Go. Along with Hoare's team at Oxford, David May concurrently developed *Occam*, a language deliberately intended to blend CSP into a practical programming language. CSP and Occam influenced each other (for example in [*The Laws of Occam Programming*](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3376/PRG53.pdf)). For years, Occam was only available on the Transputer processor, which had its architecture tailored to suit CSP. More recently, [Occam has developed](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/kroc/) to target other processors and has also absorbed Pi calculus, along with other general synchronisation primitives.

So, to answer the original question, it is probably helpful to compare Go with both CSP and Occam.

1. Channels: CSP, Go and Occam all have the same semantics for channels. In addition, Go makes it easy to add buffering into channels (Occam does not).
2. Choices: CSP defines both the *internal* and *external* choice. However, both Go and Occam have a single kind of selection: *select* in Go and *ALT* in Occam. The fact that there are two kinds of CSP choice proved to be less important in practical languages.
3. Occam's *ALT* allows condition guards, but Go's *select* does not (there is a workaround: channel aliases can be set to *nil* to imitate the same behaviour).
4. Mobility: Go allows channel ends to be sent (along with other data) via channels. This creates a dynamically-changing topology and goes beyond what is possible in CSP, but Milner's Pi calculus was developed (out of his CCS) to describe such networks.
5. Processes: A goroutine is a forked process; it terminates when it wants to and it doesn't have a parent. This is less like CSP / Occam, in which processes are compositional.

An example will help here: firstly Occam (n.b. indentation matters)

```
SEQ
  PAR
    processA()
    processB()
  processC()
```

and secondly Go

```
go processA()
go processB()
processC()
```

In the Occam case, processC doesn't start until both processA and processB have terminated. In Go, processA and processB fork very quickly, then processC runs straightaway.

6. Shared data: CSP is not really concerned with data directly. But it is interesting to note there is an important difference between Go and Occam concerning shared data. When multiple goroutines share a common set of data variables, race conditions are possible; Go's excellent race detector helps to eliminate problems. But Occam takes a different stance: shared mutable data is prevented at compilation time.
7. Aliases: related to the above, Go allows many pointers to refer to each data item. Such aliases are disallowed in Occam, so reducing the effort needed to detect race conditions.

The latter two points are less about Hoare's CSP and more about May's Occam. But they are relevant because they directly concern safe concurrent coding.

Comment: Didn't get it about Java's mistake :)

Comment: In Hoare's Monitors, a thread can be put to sleep. When it wakes, it is in the *same state*; time has passed but nothing impairs its ability to carry on. In Java though, a thread will awake in a different state: it's now at the back of the run queue. This is dealt with using a **while** instead of **if**, but Welch's example shows how it can cause pathological behaviour that, in his example, results in starvation of one or more threads.

Comment: One of the things I'm very interested in is Rust's version of CSP. With Rust's knowledge of memory ownership and mutability it has the opportunity to implement CSP by passing ownership down channels, instead of data, and still be CSP. That could make it pretty fast, and with consistent transmission times. I remember in the old days on Transputers that channels between chips were a lot slower than internal channel, which was always a nuissance when load balancing a real time system... It is very nice to see CSP making a return in popular languages!

Comment: That's a really good parallel. In is theoretical form, CSP channels are about events. The exchange of data via channels can have different implementations so passing data by copying or by using references, pointers or ownership seems equally valid to me.

Comment: I wrote https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rickb777/process to model CSP processes better in Go. All it does is handle the join when a group of goroutines terminate

Answer (score 7):

That's exactly the point: in the example language used in Hoare's initial paper (and also in Erlang), process A talks directly to process B, while in Go, goroutine A talks to channel C and goroutine B listens to channel C. I.e. in Go the channels are *explicit* while in Hoare's language and Erlang, they are *implicit*.

See [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly/1768317) for more info.

Comment: This is not historically complete and somewhat misrepresents Hoare's work.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've been working quite intensively with Go's channels, and have been working with concurrency and parallelism for many years, although I could never profess to know everything about this.

I think what you're asking is what's the subtle difference between sending a message to a channel and sending directly to each other?  If I understand you, the quick answer is simple.

Sending to a Channel give the opportunity for parallelism / concurrency on both sides of the channel.  Beautiful, and scalable.

We live in a concurrent world.   Sending a long continuous stream of messages from A to B (asynchronously) means that B will need to process the messages at pretty much the same pace as A sends them, unless more than one instance of B has the opportunity to process a message taken from the channel, hence sharing the workload.

The good thing about channels is that that you can have a number of producer/receiver go-routines which are able to push messages to the queue, or consume from the queue and process it accordingly.

If you think linearly, like a single-core CPU, concurrency is basically like having a million jobs to do.  Knowing a single-core CPU can only do one thing at a time, and yet also see that it gives the illusion that lots of things are happening at the same time. When executing some code, the time the OS needs to wait a while for something to come back from the network, disk, keyboard, mouse, etc, or even some process which sleeps for a while, give the OS the opportunity to do something else in the meantime.   This all happens extremely quickly, creating the illusion of parallelism.

Parallelism on the other hand is different in that the job can be run on a completely different CPU independent of what's going with other CPUs, and therefore doesn't run under the same constraints as the other CPU (although most OS's do a pretty good job at ensuring workloads are evenly distributed to run across all of it's CPUs - with perhaps the exception of CPU-hungry, uncooperative non-os-yielding-code, but even then the OS tames them.

The point is, having multi-core CPUs means more parallelism and more concurrency can occur.

Imagine a single queue at a bank which fans-out to a number of tellers who can help you. If no customers are being served by any teller, one teller elects to handle the next customer and becomes busy, until they all become busy.   Whenever a customer walks away from a teller, that teller is able to handle the next customer in the queue.